# Retrieving pages for a newly created admin user of a page returns empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My applicaton uses this endpoint to retrieve a list of pages to which a user has access.

For my personal account, which is the admin of a page, it works fine:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[accesstoken_for_my_personal_profile]

```
Results:
{
   "data": [
      {
         "access_token": "<the access token>",
         "category": "Record Label",
         "name": "Page Name",
         "id": "Page ID",
         "perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
         ]
      }
    ]
}
```

But when we create a totally new facebook profile (regular user, as per my personal one) - and get it verified using mobile phone / SMS based verification, it only ever returns blank here, despite being given page admin access to the same page and having requested an access token exactly the same way:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[accesstoken_for_newly_created_profile]

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

**UPDATE**
The access token permissions are also different.

So when calling https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=xxx, the bad user only has public_profile and installed as 'granted' - but the good user has all the requested permissions including 'manage_pages'.

The URL used to request the tokens in the first place is here:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[my_app_id]&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=manage_pages,read_mailbox,read_stream,publish_actions,user_likes&response_type=token

This directs to a login page which logs in as the user for which we want a token.

Comment: Debug the access token for the “new” user, and see if it actually contains the permissions you think it does. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: No it doesn't - I'll update the question because the request for the access token was identical to the 'working' user.  As if it wasn't able to issue a token with the requested permissions, watch out for the question update shortly.

Comment: Does the new user have a role in the app? Otherwise, you need to get your permissions reviewed by Facebook, before common users can be asked for them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#review

Comment: Neither user have the app come up under 'apps' in their respective accounts, if that's what you mean.  There are users that have worked in the past which haven't had roles in the app specifically assigned.

Comment: No, that’s not what I mean, I mean if this user is assigned an admin, developer or tester role in your app.

Comment: My personal account is, yes - I am the developer who created the app.  But like I say, we've requested these access tokens for other users in the past who don't have roles in the app - and they have worked/been able to post/have successfully got the "manage_pages" permission in their token.

Comment: actually i 'll delete this question and raise another one specifically about the access token request !

Comment: Does “in the past” mean, before API v2.0 was introduced? Since then, you need to get your permissions reviewed, see link above.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @CBroe above:

The issue here was that since API v2.0 came in, requesting access tokens for users who do *not* have a role in the requesting app will not assign certain permissions (in our case 'manage_pages') unless the app has been reviewed.